# bpf_asm returns single ' on compile

Tags: linux-kernel, bpf

I am new to Berkeley Packet Filter . I am trying to learn how to hand roll my own bpf code and then compile it using the bpf_asm. I am working on ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.4.0-137. I have downloaded the source code and I am working my way through  the recommended reading, in `Documentation/networking`, specifically `[filter.txt][1]`. I have install `binutils`, built and installed `bpf_asm` located in `tools/net` using the provided makefile. Everything to this point appears to have gone okay. When I run `bpf_asm -c bpf_example` the program produces a single ' mark to standard out. The code I am trying to compile is the sample code provided in `Documentation/networking/filter.txt` I am including it here for completeness.

```
  ld [4]                  /* offsetof(struct seccomp_data, arch) */
  jne #0xc000003e, bad    /* AUDIT_ARCH_X86_64 */
  ld [0]                  /* offsetof(struct seccomp_data, nr) */
  jeq #15, good           /* __NR_rt_sigreturn */
  jeq #231, good          /* __NR_exit_group */
  jeq #60, good           /* __NR_exit */
  jeq #0, good            /* __NR_read */
  jeq #1, good            /* __NR_write */
  jeq #5, good            /* __NR_fstat */
  jeq #9, good            /* __NR_mmap */
  jeq #14, good           /* __NR_rt_sigprocmask */
  jeq #13, good           /* __NR_rt_sigaction */
  jeq #35, good           /* __NR_nanosleep */
  bad: ret #0             /* SECCOMP_RET_KILL_THREAD */
  good: ret #0x7fff0000   /* SECCOMP_RET_ALLOW */
```

The output that is mentioned in `filter.txt` is

```
$ ./bpf_asm -c foo
{ 0x28,  0,  0, 0x0000000c },
{ 0x15,  0,  1, 0x00000806 },
{ 0x06,  0,  0, 0xffffffff },
{ 0x06,  0,  0, 0000000000 },
```

However, my output is

```
./bpf_asm -c bpf_example
'
```

I am clearly messing something up. Can someone point out what I have overlooked, provide suggestions for things to try, or provide additional literature supplementary to `filter.txt`?
Thank you.

### Edit

After reading the code more carefully I found that bpf_exp.y was invoking yyerror. With a message "lex unknown character", which I find somewhat strange since I yanked the text from `filter.txt` directly into a new file. Playing with bpf_exp.l I found some strange behavior in the production for `.`, which is used to catch any output that is not caught by the rest of the lexer and output an error. Commenting those out... which is probably a terrible idea, I was able to produce bpf output. However, it isn't equivalent to what `filter.txt` suggests as the output. It does however contain the same number of lines as the bpf that was input and after running it through the `bpf_dbg` program I recovered the same output that I input. Is this program no longer maintained? Or I am still not using it correctly? Furthermore, it would seem very difficult for the input bpf program in `filter.txt` to be output as the suggested program since I don't believe the parser has any sort of optimization for the output code. Hence it would seem like it needs to have the same number of line. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: Copy-pasting the program in `foo` and running `./bpf_asm -c foo` works fine for me, without having to change anything. Maybe try with a recent kernel? I suppose you use an old one as `bpf_asm.c` moved from tools/net to tools/bpf some time ago now. As for your edit on output length, yes it should be the same length as your original program. The thing here is that you simply misread filter.txt: `Example with above
ARP code:`, the output you pasted is for the ARP program, not the SEGCOMP program you want to turn into asm (and I do get 15 lines of output from `bpf_asm` for this SEGCOMP program).

Comment: You are definitely  correct about misreading. Thank you. I will give it a try with a modern kernel and report back.

Comment: @Qeole you are correct. It works great on kernel 4.19.2